# Querying in MongoDB using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have a Product class which contains about 2 million of data. Each row in Product table has a field called property which contains hash values. I have search box and the value entered in search box should be searched within the hash values of the Products table. How do I do that? I am using MongoDB and Rails. This is what I tried so far.

```
@product3= Product.select{|hash| hash.property.has_value? /.*#{params[:search]}*./i}
```

It returns undefined method 'select' for Product class. So I tried like below.

```
@product3= Product.all.to_a.select{|hash| hash.property.has_value? /.*#{params[:search]}*./i}
```

But it is looping to all the data(2 million) which takes bunch of time.

EDIT: Image for sample data from Products table. 
I have shown 2 records from products table using the query `Product.limit(2).all.to_a`.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your db structure?

Comment: @Shrabanee. Thank you. Updated the question. Please take a look at the attached Image.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one For Like Query

```
/.*#{params[:search]}.*/i
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please help me with complete query.